# How to avoid overflow in embedded python block in GNURadio?

Tags: gnuradio

I am currently working on project which utilizes RTL-SDR for capturing packets. I want to capture packets incoming on two different channels. I created the following RF path and it works just fine in terms of capturing packets and converting them into digital form.

[image: RFPath]

However I want to scrap the payloads of those packets. I correlate the SFD and the Correlate Access Code block outputs in strings of zeros and ones, number two whenever SFD is matched. Knowing that I wrote a custom python block with simple if statement which is looking for those number two's. And this is where problem begins. Without my custom packet parser block everything works just fine, but with it in RF path, flowgraph immediately gets overloaded and barely any packets are captured. I have placed the implementation of packet parse block below. Why is this block causing such massive overload? It's a really simple implementation of a block. I know that samle rate is a troublemaker when we deal with overloading but I am not really willing with going down with sample rate any further. Is there a way of allowing GNURadio to use more CPU? GNURadio is using only 13% of my CPU. I am glad to give more however I don't know how. I was also thinking about usage of multithreading - running multiple concurrent loops which would partition and scrap incoming collections of bits.

```
class blk(gr.sync_block): 

    def __init__(self, path='somePath', channel='channel'):  

        gr.sync_block.__init__(
            self,
            name='Packet parser',   
            in_sig=[np.byte],
            out_sig=[]
        )
        
        self.path = path
        self.channel = channel

    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        
        for i in range(len(input_items[0])):
                   
            if input_items[0][i] == 2:  
                conn = sqlite3.connect("anotherPath")
                timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now())
                input_items[0][i] = 0
                somePayloadBitsChanged = self.littleEndianToBig(input_items[0][i:i+64])
                conn.execute(f"INSERT INTO Log (Guid,Timestamp,Channel,SomePayloadBitsChanged ) VALUES ('{uuid.uuid4()}', '{timestamp}', '{self.channel}', '{somePayloadBitsChanged } )");
                conn.commit()
                conn.close()
        
        return 0
        
    def littleEndianToBig(self, somePayloadBits):
    
        try:
            array = np.array(somePayloadBits)
            array = np.packbits(array, bitorder='big')
            
            somePayloadBitsChanged = array[0]
        except:
            print("littleEndianToBig error")
            return 0
            
        return somePayloadBitsChanged
```

Comment: "Only using 13% of my CPU" — and does your machine happen to have 8 logical cores?

Comment: No, it does not. 6 physical and 12 logical cores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making one mistake that totally blocks your whole processing and means it can't work, and as explained in Hobbs' answer, which misses that mistake, commit a lot of performance sins.

## The Blocker

If your work returns 0 in any case, your block never consumes any input and your flowgraph immediately stalls. If you're not aware of that, maybe it's time to revisit the [official GNU Radio tutorials](https://tutorials.gnuradio.org), and check what the work function does, specifically.

## The Bug that Indicates Confusion

Also, I don't know what the intention behind

```
            input_items[0][i] = 0
```

is, but it's utterly illegal: you must never modify the input to a block! It also makes no sense, because you're not going to read it again if you constructed your python block correctly.

## The Performance Sins

Other than that, as hobbs says, opening and closing a database in the work function is a terrible idea. The work function is called thousands and thousands of times during the lifetime of your flowgraph, and you win absolutely nothing by reopening every time. So, in `__init__`, do something like `self.conn = sqlite3.connect("anotherPath")`, and use `self.conn` from  thereon. Even better, do it in the `def start(self):` that you can add to your class, as that is executed shortly before the flowgraph starts running. Close the connection in the `def stop(self):` method.

Your UUID entry makes little sense here. Your database has functionality to insert an unambigous key for every row, automatically. Use that instead!

You can of course use the stringified timestamp, but I found it usually way more useful (and faster, too!) to use the `clock_gettime` nanosecond clock, and store these as 64-bit integer. Convert to the readable clock format on retrieval! Doing it that way enabled easy sorting, stores way less data, and doesn't have any of the potential timezone/stringconversion/locale bugs your solution might exhibit. So, instead of `timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now())`, use `timestamp = time.time_ns()` and be done with it. Of course, your `Timestamp` column needs to get the `Int` type (instead of `Text` / `Varchar`). In a proper relational database system, you'd also avoid storing the string "864.4 MHz" in every row. Instead, you'd have a `channels` database, check at startup whether that string is already in there, and then just use the ID of that row as `Channel` value in your `Log` table.

Generally, avoid putting your values into the SQL string, as that requires numerics->string conversion, followed by string tokenization, parsing, conversion to numerics, and storage; instead, use placeholders:

```
self.conn.execute("INSERT INTO Log (Timestamp, Channel, SomePayloadBitsChanged ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                  timestamp,
                  self.channel,
                  somePayloadBitsChanged
             );
```

Then, realize that you're really just looking for the set of indices in the input where the value is `2`. Numpy makes that easy:

```
# this can be a static class member – it's not going to change.
SQL_QUERY = """
    INSERT INTO Log (
         Timestamp, Channel, SomePayloadBitsChanged
         )
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
"""
def work(self, input_items, output_items):
    inp = input_items[0] # just makes life easier
    # We're looking for 2 in everything but the last 64 items,
    # because we need the 64 items following the 2
    indices = numpy.where(inp[:-64] == 2)
    if indices: # if that list weren't empty
        self.conn.execute_many(self.SQL_QUERY,
                               zip(
                               [time.time_ns()] * len(indices),
                               [self.channel] * len(indices),
                               [self.littleEndianToBig(inp[i:i+64]) for i in indices]
                               ))
    # finally, tell GNU Radio that we've worked on all the input
    # (aside from the last 64 items, see above), and want to have
    # new data, not be presented with the same items again.
    return max(0, len(inp) - 64)
```

Comment: Thank you Marcus for your answer. I have marked this question as an answer since The Blocker paragraph is indeed an answer to my question. After that everything went smoothly. I might have overlooked something but none of the tutorials shown what should be returned when the block is an endpoint in the path. Returning of zero was a huge mistake. The bug that indicates confusion is a hardcoded way of avoiding exception in littleEndianToBig method. Since [0][i] element is a "2" not "1" or "0" an exception is thrown. Since I have only 60 chars left for rest of your comment I just say thank you :D

Comment: You're more than welcome! Overwriting your input buffer *really* is a bug though, which you realize once you put another block in parallel with it: all blocks connected to the same output share the same input buffer (it's the same ring buffer as the output is written into), and since there's no guaranteed ordering, you might never modify your input buffer.

Comment: The fact that it's nowhere mentioned should be remedied!

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't open and close the database connection for every insert; open it in `__init__` (or better, a `start` method — thanks Marcus Müller), and close it in a `stop` method.
2. Don't commit once per row inserted; once per `work` call should be more than enough. Batching up values until you have, say, a thousand, and flushing them all in a single statement would probably be even better.
3. Consider using [pragma synchronous=OFF](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous) so that sqlite doesn't block gnuradio on fsync.
4. There's almost certainly a more efficient way to write your `littleEndianToBig` function... especially since it consumes 64 bits and you're only returning 8 of them. At the very least you could save numpy some work by only giving it the 8 bits you're going to use, but there may be a better way (also, I think the function name is misleading).
5. If that's not enough, you could do all of the sqlite work in a separate worker thread that receives values from the block using a [thread queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html).
6. Or just write the relevant data out to a file in the rawest practical form and postprocess it later, which will probably be a thousand times faster than all this.

Comment: Nice answer! What I like about the sqlite solution is the inherent thread-safety. also, doing file writing more efficiently than sqlite (if you don't commit all the time, especially) from Python is a bit challenging. Honestly, for the write rates I'd expect, this might actually do pretty fine.

Comment: (though I do want to point out that all that you write could be solved with "get a faster computer". The `return 0` bug of the code could not – the flow graph is working *as designed* by stalling.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for catching that and writing your own answer. I'm not nearly as familiar with gnuradio as you are, so I paid less attention to the "meat" of the code :)

Comment: Your answer is really well written and well observed!

Comment: Thank you hobbs for your comment as well. As stated in my comment under Marcus comment his suggestion had the biggest impact on perfomance since the correct answer mark for him. I am ashamed for making such a rookie mistake as placing connection establishment in loop. I am even more ashamed for showing this mistake to the entire world. That was 5th or 6th attempt to resolve this issue and probably in anger I posted whatever I had currently in draft. I had an implementation with txt file but I was afraid that two blocks writing to the same file with packets coming really fast will cause trouble

Comment: I guess that premature optimization is the root of all evil, indeed